# How to open a link in a in-app browser window in flutter and how to change browser window header

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-web

I would like to know how to open links in an in-app browser, just like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI3NH.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [flutter_webview](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin.
Example code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter WebView example'),
        // This drop down menu demonstrates that Flutter widgets can be shown over the web view.
        actions: <Widget>[
          NavigationControls(_controller.future),
          SampleMenu(_controller.future),
        ],
      ),
      // We're using a Builder here so we have a context that is below the Scaffold
      // to allow calling Scaffold.of(context) so we can show a snackbar.
      body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return WebView(
          initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
            _controller.complete(webViewController);
          },
          onProgress: (int progress) {
            print("WebView is loading (progress : $progress%)");
          },
          javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>{
            _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
          },
          navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
            if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
              print('blocking navigation to $request}');
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            }
            print('allowing navigation to $request');
            return NavigationDecision.navigate;
          },
          onPageStarted: (String url) {
            print('Page started loading: $url');
          },
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
            print('Page finished loading: $url');
          },
          gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
        );
      }),
      floatingActionButton: favoriteButton(),
    );
  }
```